# Run cron job in symfony

Tags: symfony, docker, cron

I'm using docker for may symfony application and I need to run a cron job every minute. So basically I have a command **my:command** which I normally run like this: `app/console my:command` I tried several variations but all were unsuccessful. So my question is how can I run a cron job? 
Here are some of my tries:

First:

```
* * * * * cd /usr/lib/myProject && app/console my:command >> /usr/lib/myProject/app/logs/log1.log
```

Second:

```
* * * * * /usr/lib/myProject/app/console my:command >> /usr/lib/myProject/app/logs/log1.log
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the 'php' before 'app/console'? Also in symfony3 it should be 'bin/console'.

Comment: I'm using symfony2 that's why it is app/console. I tried to add php but still not working

Answer (score 1):

is your cronjob in your docker Image or outside? If it's outside your should check that php is already installed. You can run the command `whereis php` or `which php` to get to know the absolute path to the php binary. 
Then you put the path for the app/console command.

If your cronjob is inside of your docker container, you must to check that the cron daemon should run as a process. Use `docker ps` for it or go inside your container and execute `ps awwx`. If crond not already running I would suggest you take a look at supervisord. With this software you can run more than one process in one docker container.

At least posibility you can configure the cronjob outside but execute the command inside of the container. To do this you should prepand `docker exec` command in your crontab.

Hope it helps.

Cheers, 
Robin

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try your approach as soon as possible :) Cheers